# How to select partial values from drop down list not all

Tags: excel

From the picture, what I want is when the user input the wanted value in [H3]. If i have 10 values in the table and the user input 5. I want the dropdown list to show only 1 to 5.

[image]

Comment: Where is the code you have tried already and what problems did you have with it?

Comment: Can I do it without coding because I don't have the code

Comment: how about explain the reasoning of setting a limit to the drop down list? it can be done quite easily with a helper column if that's an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a data validation list to your input cells and set the list reference to:

```
=OFFSET(F4, 0, 0, H3, 1)
```